# What is the correct type declaration for this function?

Tags: haskell

The following function will not load:

```
charName :: a -> String
charName 'a' = "Alpha"
charName 'b' = "Bravo"
charName 'c' = "Charlie"
charName 'd' = "Delta"
charName 'e' = "Echo"
charName 'f' = "Foxtrot"
charName 'g' = "Golf"
charName 'h' = "Hotel"
charName 'i' = "India"
charName 'j' = "Juliet"
charName 'k' = "Kilo"
charName 'l' = "Lima"
charName 'm' = "mike"
charName 'n' = "November"
charName 'o' = "Oscar"
charName 'p' = "Papa"
charName 'q' = "Quebec"
charName 'r' = "Romeo"
charName 's' = "Sierra"
charName 't' = "Tango"
charName 'u' = "Uniform"
charName 'v' = "Victor"
charName 'w' = "Whiskey"
charName 'x' = "X-ray"
charName 'y' = "Yankee"
charName 'z' = "Zulu"
charName 0 = "Zero"
charName 1 = "One"
charName 2 = "Two"
charName 3 = "Three"
charName 4 = "Four"
charName 5 = "Five"
charName 6 = "Six"
charName 7 = "Seven"
charName 8 = "Eight"
charName 9 = "Nine"
charName x = ""
```

It gives me the following error:

> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( baby.hs, interpreted )
>
> baby.hs:41:9:
>       Couldn't match expected type `a' against inferred type`Char'
>         `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
>             the type signature for`charName' at baby.hs:40:12
>       In the pattern: 'a'
>       In the definition of `charName': charName 'a' = "Alpha"
>
> baby.hs:67:9:
>       No instance for (Num Char)
>         arising from the literal `0' at baby.hs:67:9
>       Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Char)
>       In the pattern: 0
>       In the definition of`charName': charName 0 = "Zero"
>   Failed, modules loaded: none.

Not sure how I can get this to work.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Your 0, 1, 2... 8, 9 are actually numbers not characters. Try adding '0', '1', '2' to them so they are characters.

Comment: This shouldn't be community wiki.

Comment: What if I want to accept numbers as input?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### With new data type

The simple way to pass either Char or Int as a function argument, is to define a new data type to encapsulate them:

```
data (Num a) => CharOrNum a = C Char | N a

charName (C 'z') = "Zulu"
charName (N 0) = "Zero"
```

Then you can use it like

```
ghci> charName $ C 'z'
"Zulu"
ghci> charName $ N 0
"Zero"
```

With this change the type of `charName` is  `(Num t) => CharOrNum t -> [Char]`.

#### With new type class

Another way is to define a common type class for both of the argument types, like `Show`.

```
class Nameable a where
  nameit :: a -> String

instance Nameable Char where
  nameit 'z' = "Zulu"
  nameit _ = ""

instance Nameable Integer where
  nameit 0 = "Zero"
  nameit _ = ""
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
ghci> (nameit 0, nameit 'z')
("Zero","Zulu")
```

Comment: Of course the Nameable is the same as Either , make your own, use a predefined one, choose yourself... I prefer the new type class version, becomes a little less verbose in the long run, and extends beautifully...

Answer (score 5):

The types of the argument in the different cases of `charName` do not match. Sometimes you use a `Char` (for example `'a'`) and sometimes you use a number (for example `9`).

There is no way you can make this work by just changing the type signature. (Well, there is one way: add an instance `Num Char`, but that would be a really bad idea).

The only sane way to achieve what you intended to do is change the numbers to `Char`s (i.e. `'0'` instead of `0` etc.).

Comment: I want to be bad how would I add an instance "Num Char"

Comment: Actually the first error is not because he is mixing Char and Int, but because charName is declared to have type a -> String so it has to work for all possible a's.

Comment: djv I am not sure what you mean by that.  I believe I am solving for all possible a's with (charName x = "") at the end.

Comment: What if changing 0 to '0' is not an option.  The function will be getting numbers as inputs.

Comment: @djv is correct. You are not "solving for all possible a's" because this single definition has to work for _every specific_ a, and it won't typecheck, because most types (that is, all of them except `Char`) can't be compared for equality to `Char`.

Comment: In fact, the bare type `a` can't be compared for equality to anything. You'd need an `Eq` instance for that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to decide on the type of the parameter. Char or Int?
`charName 'a'` to `charName 'z'` take a Char as a parameter. `charName 0` to `charName 9` take an Int. and `charName x` takes ... well, any type.

I'd change `charName 0` into `charName '0'` etc etc
and use `charName _ = ""` to match any other single Char, other than the listed:

```
...
charName 'y' = "Yankee"
charName 'z' = "Zulu"
charName '0' = "Zero"
...
charName '9' = "Nine"
charName _ = ""
```

With this changes, the function type is: charName :: Char -> String